# how to add pagination to my web based database using php and mysql

Tags: php

I've come across a problem - but any help would be appreciated.

When I query the database using the results posted from a form, the pagination works initially i.e. for the first 10 records but when I click on the 2 hyperlink of the pagination for the second page of results it loses the $_POST variable and returns to the full data set.

What is the best way of keeping these variables available for the second (and further) pages?

thanks for reply:
still i have a problem, can any one help me please , the below is my complete php file 
thanks in advance

```
    <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="design.css">
</head>


<body>

<?php
include("header.php");
?>
<center>
<div id="content" class="frm">

<a href='admin.php' style='float:left'>Back!</a>
<h2>Search Result</h2>
<br><br>
<?php

include("../config.inc");
     $find=$_GET['find'];           
           // get page no and set it to page variable, if no page is selected so asign first page bydefualt
             if (isset($_GET["page"])){
                    $page  = $_GET["page"]; 
                } 
                else {
                    $page=1;
                }
                // count all record in this table then divide it on 10 in order to find the last page----- every page has 10 record display
                    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tt where TTT='$find' "; 
                    $rs_result = mysql_query($sql); 
                    $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result); 
                    $total_records = $row[0]; 
                    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / 2);
                    // this line check that page no must be in integer format
                    $page = (int)$page;
                    if ($page > $total_pages) {
                    $page = $total_pages;
                    } // if
                    if ($page < 1) {
                    $page= 1;
                    } // if

                    $start_from = ($page-1) * 2;

$q=mysql_query("select * from tt where TTT='$find' order by ID limit $start_from,2");
$c=mysql_query("select count(*) from tt where TTT='$find'");
echo "<center>".mysql_result($c,0)."Filtered</center>";
echo "<center>";
echo "<table border='2' bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
<tr>
<th>TTT</th>
<th>Enroll Date</th>
<th>Gradution Date</th>
<th>ID</th>
</tr>";

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['TTT']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Enroll_Date']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Graduation_Date']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['ID']."</td>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<center>";

              // paginatio start here 
              if ($page== 1) {
              echo " << < ";
              } else {
             echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=1'><<</a> ";
             $prevpage = $page-1;
               echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$prevpage'><</a> ";
             } // if
             echo " ( Page [$page] of [$total_pages] ) ";

             if ($page == $total_pages) {
             echo " > >> ";
             } else {
              $nextpage = $page+1;
              echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$nextpage'>></a> ";
              $lastpage=$total_pages;
              echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$lastpage'>>></a> ";
              } // if
?>

</div>
</center>

<?php
include("footer.php");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice says to not use POST method if your query doesn't alter the state of your system. For example, in your case I wouldn't submit a POST request but I'd use GET.

That way your pagination links should preserve your query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use POST in the first place. POST is for sending data to be acted on. GET is for sending data that describes what you want to read. If you are paginating, then you are reading things.

Then make sure your links contain all the data you need to describe what it is you want the second (or third or etc) page to contain.

Answer (score 0):

Its usefull to get a pre-written pagination class if you are inexperienced making one yourself. (if not ignore this awnser)

You could use something like this

http://www.catchmyfame.com/2011/10/23/php-pagination-class-updated-version-2/